# Filter / select folders using wildcards

Tags: mercurial, glob

For my [mecurial ignore file](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) I want to select all the folders that start with `dataset` in my project folder with with one 'glob statement'.

Example project folder:

```
my_project_folder/
   dataset1/
   dataset2/
   dataset3/
   code.py
```

I tried `dataset*/` but that selects nothing. What would be the right statement?

Answer (score 4):

```
syntax: regexp
/dataset.*/
^/dataset.*/
```

See [hgignore](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore) for explanation of the syntax.